# Always keep tables in memory using Entity Framework but allow for dynamic refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, static-constructor

I've got scenario with a very small ASP.NET MVC application in which I need to load the contents of two EF tables (both under 100 records) in memory forever. Instead of reading from the database, the application is expected to use the memory-cached tables (i.e. object lists) for mapping requests.

The only caveat to this is that there is a need to be able to refresh the cache. A simple POST request to any exposed URL with the appropriate credentials should be enough to do this.

Given that the application is also built n-tier, I tried to build a static repository class that initializes the lists in a static constructor and exposes them via public methods. I'm having issues where the context does not initialize and the lists come out empty when I deploy to IIS. Locally, they initialize just fine.

Is this approach a valid way to go about this given the size of the application or is there a more preferred approach to go about this?

Repo Code:

```
public static class MyRepository
    {
        static DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

        private static List<Obj> ObjectsT { get; set; }

        static MyRepository()
        {
            //Initialize cache for first time use
            RefreshListCache();
        }

        public static bool RefreshListCache()
        {
                ObjectsT = db.Objs.Select(x => new Obj()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
                    Val = x.Val
                }).ToList();

                return true;
        }

        public static Obj GetObjById(string id)
        {
            return Objs.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show some code. Is this ASP.NET Core or do you have dependency injection set up in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @MichaelTranchida It's ASP.NET MVC. I've added code for the repo.

Comment: Looks like you should be pulling stuff from the database, you sure your database has data in it? Have you stepped through the code in debug? Definite code smell with the DbContext, at the very least, you should dispose it after populating list. When you post changes, should they be persisted to the database?